# How to abort function and return to main tkinter window using messagebox

Tags: python, tkinter

My tkinter script has a pull-down menu to call `my_function`. This in turn calls `external_function` from an imported package. It could happen that `external_function` produces a warning messsage. Should this occur, I want to treat this warning as an error, terminate `my_function` and return to the root window. I'm looking for the right method, e.g. keyword combination in messagebox, to make that happen.

Here's a synopsis of the code I've tried, where root is my main tkinter window

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("error") # treats warnings as errors

def my_function(input, root):
    try:
        external_function_output=external_function(input)
    except:
        messagebox.showerror("Error",["Try again",root])
        return
    return external_function_output
```

In essence, I want to add something within `messagebox.showerror` so that when one presses the okay button on the message box, `my_function` terminates and I'm just staring at my root window. Of course, as written above, nothing happens when I press the button.

Comment: Does your external function create another window at all? Does it force the root to disappear?

Comment: No it does not. It merely performs calculations and returns an instance of a class I created.

Comment: Then you should be able to just have `messagebox.showerror("Error", "Try again")` in your except clause and it will return you to your main window

Comment: Thanks much. That seems to work!